# How do I tell if there is an iPhone backup in my iCloud account without the iPhone

Tags: iphone, icloud, backup, apple-id, accounts

A couple of months ago I had an iPhone. 
That iPhone was never connected to iTunes. It was configured to make backups to iCloud. It was stolen.

Now I'm getting another, used iPhone from a family member. It would be nice if I could restore the backup of my previous iPhone to the newer iPhone.

But since I no longer have my previous iPhone, I don't know if there still is a backup to restore. If there is none, I don't want to reset the new iPhone.

Is there a way to tell if the backup is still in my iCloud account?

Answer (score 4):

Simply log in into iCloud Control Panel on your Mac or PC (using your Apple ID and password) and press [Storage]; you will see the list of available devices/backups on the
account:

[image: iCLoud backups]